# Google Maps UI missing in extended controls - Android Emulator

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, user-interface, manjaro

[image]

I'm on `Manjaro`, completely remove and then installed back Android Studio, but nothing seems to work.

I have `Windows` and `Manjaro` both on the same machine, on Windows it works as expected. I have no clue why it's not working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same error, fresh install of Manjaro, installed studio from AUR

Comment: I am facing the same problem on Arch Linux when installing Android Studio from the AUR. My workaround is to install it via Flatpak instead (https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.google.AndroidStudio).

Comment: Installing via Flatpak solved this issue for me partly. When the emulator runs embedded in Android Studio it works, launching it as standalone it does not, unfortunately.

Comment: Issue still persists when running emulator through terminal or installing it through other sources, as @tobhai said using the flatpak app seems to work for some reason, any idea why? It is not a distro issue also tested on Fedora.

Comment: Same problem in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Any solution??

Comment: @John upgrade the emulator to version `32.1.1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue has been fixed as of Android Emulator version `32.1.1`, just upgrade through `Android Studio`.

This is where the issue was report to google devs:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228201899